# Not able to launch Tizen Native App

Tags: launch, tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I am not able to launch Tizen Native App.Its stuck on 74%.In logs its showing cannot create package.
The last message on console while the launch was stuck on 74% was:

---

Signing...
C: && cd C:\tizen-sdk\tools\smart-build-interface..\ide\bin && cmd.exe /C native-signing.bat "C:\Documents and Settings\user\workspace\helloworld2\Debug.tpk" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\developer\tizen-developer-ca.cer" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\singh.p12" "****" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-signer.p12" "****" "C:\tizen-sdk\tools\certificate-generator\certificates\distributor\tizen-distributor-ca.cer" "" "****" "" ""

---

Please,note that the emulator is showing in the connection explorer and i have already worked several times with the same emulator instance before.

Can anyone help with this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you already created certificate, delete it and generate a new one.
The same with security profile in Tizen IDE -> Window -> Preferences -> Tizen SDK -> Security Profiles: delete old one and create a new.

Also, check time on your PC and on emulator. It shouldn't be significantly different, otherwise you may have signature validity issue.

Additionally, please, in future add info about SDK version you use. I recommend to use latest stable 2.2.

Comment: I did many a things......its working fine now...though not sure what was the cause and what fixed it..as of now i am using 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, a shared access issue?

If there was a system restart or closing opened files in-between - that should be a reason.

The other reason could be device deployment issue. If certificate is 'too new' (the real reason here is when the time on device is **way** behind real time), Tizen could decide that certificate is not valid.